# Unable to understand the flow of list serializer update in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using list Serializer by many = True. The create method is running perfectly but i am unable to understand the flow of custom update method of list serializer in documentation of django rest framework. Using the base of list serializer is clear but when i am using it in code the flow is not understandable. I am not able to understand what book.items mean in the fourth line.  What is book ? In the documentation it is also asking to add an explicit id field to the instance serializer. The default implicitly-generated id field is marked as read_only. Looking to understand what documentation is saying and how to implement it. The context from documentation is give below.

```
class BookListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    # Maps for id->instance and id->data item.
    book_mapping = {book.id: book for book in instance}
    data_mapping = {item['id']: item for item in validated_data}

    # Perform creations and updates.
    ret = []
    for book_id, data in data_mapping.items():
        book = book_mapping.get(book_id, None)
        if book is None:
            ret.append(self.child.create(data))
        else:
            ret.append(self.child.update(book, data))

    # Perform deletions.
    for book_id, book in book_mapping.items():
        if book_id not in data_mapping:a
            book.delete()

    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

`instance` is a list of books, i.e. objects of the class that shall be serialized. `validated_data` is a list of data dictionaries, where each `item` is similar to what the `validated_data` you get passed, if you use a not list serializer. To access the id of a book object, you use `book.id`, to access the id of the items in `validated_data`, you use item['id'].
You need a non read_only id field for the reason, that if you want to put a list of objects and replace a whole collection, you need to pass ids in order to define, if an item shall update an existing item and if so, which one, or if an item is new. That is what happens in the loops: in the first one, items are either created or updated, depending on wether objects with the same id exist or not. In the last loop, all items that don't appear in `validated_data` are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

DRF's documentation sometimes is a bit too "expect you to understand where x and y comes from" instead of having more clear examples. It might help pushing improved code to your codebase, however, improved code is not always better in terms of code readability (which should also be a big part of a developers skills).

Anyway, I had the same issue with the code you presented and after some tinkering, i figured it out.

> ```py
>     # Maps for id->instance and id->data item.
>     book_mapping = {book.id: book for book in instance}
>     data_mapping = {item['id']: item for item in validated_data}
> ```

The schema of `[x for x in y]` is called [list comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) and is just a one liner way of re-formatting a list or dictionary based on a list.
Since, in these cases, the id's are always unique, one can expect that the resulting dict has unique keys that have the book or items as their values.

So, i.e., if the instance is

```py
instance = [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "hobbit",
    "author": "Megan"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Milk",
    "author": "Eric"
  },
  ...
]
```

Then the result of book mapping would be

```py
book_mapping = {book.id: book for book in instance}
book_mapping = {
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "hobbit",
    "author": "Megan"
  },
  "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Milk",
    "author": "Eric"
  }
}
```